# I don't understand how inih works

Tags: c, ini, inih

I've been trying to read an ini file with inih lib since a few hours, and I still don't totally understand this code, especially `configuration* pconfig = (configuration*)user;`, and what are the handler function parameters for ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../ini.h"

typedef struct
{
    int version;
    const char* name;
    const char* email;
} configuration;

static int handler(void* user, const char* section, const char* name,
                   const char* value)
{
    configuration* pconfig = (configuration*)user;

    #define MATCH(s, n) strcmp(section, s) == 0 && strcmp(name, n) == 0
    if (MATCH("protocol", "version")) {
        pconfig->version = atoi(value);
    } else if (MATCH("user", "name")) {
        pconfig->name = strdup(value);
    } else if (MATCH("user", "email")) {
        pconfig->email = strdup(value);
    } else {
        return 0;  /* unknown section/name, error */
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    configuration config;

    if (ini_parse("test.ini", handler, &config) < 0) {
        printf("Can't load 'test.ini'\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Config loaded from 'test.ini': version=%d, name=%s, email=%s\n",
        config.version, config.name, config.email);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What, more specifically, about `configuration* pconfig = (configuration*)user;` are you wondering about? What parts of it do you have problems with?

Comment: I finnally got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user` is a "generic pointer", or "untyped pointer".

Dereferencing that pointer would give you a value of type `void` which isn't possible.

Therefore you must cast the pointer to the correct type to be able to use it.

---

As for the arguments and what they're used for you could [read the source](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih).

But with a little knowledge of [INI files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) it should be easy to deduce that the `section` argument is the name of a section in the file, while `name` is the current value name, and `value` is the value itself.

So assuming a section and value like

```
[foo]
bar = something
```

Then `section` would be `"foo"`, `name` would be `"bar"` and `value` would be `"something"`.

And the `user` argument is very likely the third argument passed to `ini_parse`.

Answer (score 0):

`user` is obviously a pointer to `configuration` instance you gave to `ini_parse`.
`void*` is only kind of type erasure for pointers available in C.

`section` is name of section of .ini file,
`name` is key name, `value` is key's value.

`ini_parse` calls handler for every key, passing it `configuration` and  result of parsing iteration. What handler does with that information, is to be defined by user of library.

Comment: but what's this : ```configuration* pconfig = (configuration*)user;``` ?

Comment: @f566f6d are you implying you don't know language at all?  that's declaration of copy of pointer initialized with value of `user` after its conversion to concrete pointer, a pointer to  `configuration`. You can convert any pointer to `void*` implicitly, but opposite must be an explicit conversion.